# Why won't my Enaml ImageView scale down?

Tags: qt, pyqt, windows-10, pyqt5, enaml

Here is a simple Enaml file to display a single image - an [800x1210 pixel image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/800px-Mona_Lisa.jpg).

```
from enaml.widgets.api import Window, Container, ImageView
from enaml.image import Image

enamldef ImageViewResizeWindow(Window):
    Container:
        ImageView:
            image << Image(data=open("Mona_Lisa.jpg", "rb").read())
            scale_to_fit = True
            allow_upscaling = False
            preserve_aspect_ratio = True
```

The windows opens up rather large to fit the whole image in, but when I try to resize the window, it won't shrink - the image can't be downscaled, even though `scale_to_fit` is True. On the other hand, it will allow the window to be resized larger, but (correctly) won't upscale the image - it just adds more space around it.

Experimenting, I set `allow_upscaling`to True, and it allowed the image to grow, but not to shrink. It knows *how* to scale, but won't downscale.

Okay, maybe the ImageView must have a minimum size, so I added:

```
            minimum_size = (100, 100)
```

That should override the "intelligent minimum size" that was calculated for the ImageView widget, but makes no difference.

I am new to Enaml, so I suspect a basic level misunderstanding.

What do I need to do to get an ImageView to allow the downscaling of a large image, when the surrounding window is resized?

Versions:

- Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct 3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- enaml==0.10.2
- PyQt5==5.10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `resist_width` and `resist_height` to `'weak'` is the correct answer. You can set other constraints on the widget to give it a preferred size:

```
ImageView: 
    resist_width = 'weak'
    resist_height = 'weak'
    constraints = [(width == 640) | 'weak', (height == 480) | 'weak']
```

Comment: The settings `scale_to_fit = True` and `allow_upscaling = True` were also useful to me

Answer (score 0):

If I add

```
        resist_width = 'weak'
        resist_height = 'weak'
```

it will allow me to downscale.

However, it will also open at a smaller size by default.